# append something to a div in javascript without using pre tag for making newline for text

Tags: javascript, append

How i can use append to append new line to div using javascript

means the div have some line and all line show as newline like

it's me Steven
Are this fine.

I try to read some article but they tell about `\r\n \n` but they not worked. some article tell to use pre tag but i not want to use it.

are their any other good way to do it using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending the `<br />` tag

It is the html tag for a break and will make a new line that the browser will acknowledge

Comment: i know i can use it but it's append more space between line then ususal so are their any other trick to do this.

Comment: You could try breaking your paragraphs up using the `<p>` tag as Kooilnc suggests and then use css to change the space between the paragraphs.